# How to efficiently access the features returned by QgsSpatialIndex?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-index

The [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#using-spatial-index) explains how to set up the spatial index but it only explains half of its usage:

> create spatial index — the following code creates an empty index
>
> ```
> index = QgsSpatialIndex()
> ```
>
> add features to index — index takes QgsFeature object and adds it to the internal data structure. You can create the object manually or use one from previous call to provider’s nextFeature()
>
> ```
> index.insertFeature(feat)
> ```
>
> once spatial index is filled with some values, you can do some queries
>
> ```
> # returns array of feature IDs of five nearest features
> nearest = index.nearestNeighbor(QgsPoint(25.4, 12.7), 5)
> ```

What's the most efficient step to get the actual features belonging to the returned feature IDs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    # assume a list of feature ids returned from index and a QgsVectorLayer 'lyr'
    fids = [1, 2, 4]
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    request.setFilterFids(fids)

    features = lyr.getFeatures(request)
    # can now iterate and do fun stuff:
    for feature in features:
        print feature.id(), feature

    1 <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x000000000E987510>
    2 <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x000000000E987400>
    4 <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x000000000E987510>
```

Comment: Thanks! Snorfalorpagus mentioned that setFilterFids would be considerably slower than the solution he posted. Do you confirm this?

Comment: I haven't used it on large result sets so can't confirm.

Comment: I confirm and ,in my case, [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) is even faster than QgsSpatialIndex() (for construction of [Planar Graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) from very big polylines layers, transposition of the module [PlanarGraph with Shapely](https://github.com/paleroux/PlanarGraph) in PyQGIS. But the solution with Fiona, Shapely and rtree is still the fastest)

Comment: I believe the question is about obtaining the actual features from the *returned* feature ids rather than the speed of various indexing methods.

Answer (score 11):

In [a blog post on the subject](https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code//), Nathan Woodrow ([@Nathan W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/97/nathan-w)) provides the following code:

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# Select all features along with their attributes
allAttrs = layer.pendingAllAttributesList()
layer.select(allAttrs)
# Get all the features to start
allfeatures = {feature.id(): feature for (feature) in layer}

def noindex():
    for feature in allfeatures.values():
        for f in allfeatures.values():
            touches = f.geometry().touches(feature.geometry())
            # It doesn't matter if we don't return anything it's just an example

def withindex():
    # Build the spatial index for faster lookup.
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    map(index.insertFeature, allfeatures.values())

    # Loop each feature in the layer again and get only the features that are going to touch.
    for feature in allfeatures.values():
        ids = index.intersects(feature.geometry().boundingBox())
        for id in ids:
            f = allfeatures[id]
            touches = f.geometry().touches(feature.geometry())
            # It doesn't matter if we don't return anything it's just an example

import timeit
print "With Index: %s seconds " % timeit.timeit(withindex,number=1)
print "Without Index: %s seconds " % timeit.timeit(noindex,number=1)
```

This creates a dictionary allowing you to quickly look up a `QgsFeature` using it's FID.

I've found that for very large layers this isn't especially practical as it requires a lot of memory. However, the alternative (random access of the desired feature) using `layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(fid))` seems to be comparatively very slow. I'm not sure why this is, as the equivalent call using the SWIG OGR bindings `layer.GetFeature(fid)` seems much faster than this.

Comment: Using a dictionary was **very** much faster than `layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(fid))`.  I was working on a layer with 140k features, and the total time for the 140k lookups went from many minutes to seconds.

Answer (score 8):

For comparisons, look at [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103066/2581). The solution presented use the Python modules [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html), [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) and  [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) (Spatial Index).

With PyQGIS and the same example two layers, `point` and `polygon`:

[image]

1) Without a spatial index:

```
polygons = [feature for feature in polygon.getFeatures()]
points = [feature for feature in point.getFeatures()]
for pt in points: 
    point = pt.geometry()
    for pl  in polygons:
        poly = pl.geometry()
        if poly.contains(point):
            print point.asPoint(), poly.asPolygon()
(184127,122472) [[(183372,123361), (184078,123130), (184516,122631),   (184516,122265), (183676,122144), (183067,122570), (183128,123105), (183372,123361)]]
(183457,122850) [[(183372,123361), (184078,123130), (184516,122631), (184516,122265), (183676,122144), (183067,122570), (183128,123105), (183372,123361)]]
(184723,124043) [[(184200,124737), (185368,124372), (185466,124055), (185515,123714), (184955,123580), (184675,123471), (184139,123787), (184200,124737)]]
(182179,124067) [[(182520,125175), (183348,124286), (182605,123714), (182252,123544), (181753,123799), (181740,124627), (182520,125175)]]
```

2) With the [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) PyQGIS spatial index:

```
# build the spatial index with all the polygons and not only a bounding box
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for poly in polygons:
     index.insertFeature(poly)

# intersections with the index 
# indices of the index for the intersections
for pt in points:
    point = pt.geometry()
    for id in index.intersects(point.boundingBox()):
    print id
0
0
1
2
```

What does these indices mean ?

```
for i, pt in enumerate(points):
     point = pt.geometry()
     for id in index.intersects(point.boundingBox()):
        print "Point ", i, points[i].geometry().asPoint(), "is in Polygon ", id, polygons[id].geometry().asPolygon()
Point  1 (184127,122472) is in Polygon  0 [[(182520,125175), (183348,124286), (182605,123714), (182252,123544), (181753,123799), (181740,124627), (182520,125175)]]
Point  2 (183457,122850) is in Polygon  0 [[(182520,125175), (183348,124286), (182605,123714), (182252,123544), (181753,123799), (181740,124627), (182520,125175)]]
Point  4 (184723,124043) is in Polygon  1 [[(182520,125175), (183348,124286), (182605,123714), (182252,123544), (181753,123799), (181740,124627), (182520,125175)]]
Point  6 (182179,124067) is in Polygon  2 [[(182520,125175), (183348,124286), (182605,123714), (182252,123544), (181753,123799), (181740,124627), (182520,125175)]]
```

Same conclusions as in [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103066/2581):

- Without and index, you must iterate through all the geometries (polygons and points).
- With a bounding spatial index (QgsSpatialIndex()), you iterate only through the geometries which have a chance to intersect with your current geometry ('filter' which can save a considerable amount of calculations and time...).
- You can also use other spatial index Python modules ([rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/), [Pyrtree](https://code.google.com/p/pyrtree/) or [Quadtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quadtree/0.1.2)) with PyQGIS as in [Using a QGIS spatial index to speed up your code](https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code/) (with QgsSpatialIndex() and [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/))
- but a Spatial Index is not a magic wand. When a very large part of the dataset has to be retrieved, a Spatial Index cannot give any speed benefit.

Other example in GIS se: [How to find the nearest line to a point in QGIS? [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59185/2581)

Comment: Thanks for all the additional explanation. Basically, your solution uses a list instead of a dict as Snorfalorpagus did. So there really seems to be no layer.getFeatures([ids]) function ...

Comment: The purpose of this explanation is purely geometrical and it is very easy to add a  layer.getFeatures([ids]) function as in [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/103066#103066)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the only method to get good performance is to avoid or bundle calls to layer.getFeatures(), even if the filter is as simple as an fid.

> Now, here’s the trap: calling getFeatures is expensive. If you call it
>   on a vector layer, QGIS will be required to setup an new connection to
>   the data store (the layer provider), create some query to return data,
>   and parse each result as it is returned from the provider. This can be
>   slow, especially if you’re working with some type of remote layer,
>   such as a PostGIS table over a VPN connection.

source: http://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/