# Get distance from point to nearest edge of polygon with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have 2 .shp layers in my workspace, `polyLayer` and `pointLayer`

Using PyQGIS I'd like to be able to get the distance from the point to the nearest boundary of the polygon.

I've done this sort of thing successfully in PostGIS. It seems like it must be a very commonly used query, but I can't find anything on performing such queries on .shp files using PyQGIS.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: This question has already been answered several times it seems ...

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Same or "similar" i would say : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59173/how-to-find-the-nearest-line-to-a-point-in-qgis ... u can use it as starting point ...

Comment: Yep, read that, done it. It does indeed return the ID of the nearest line. I'm trying to get the distance...and need someone to show me in baby steps!

Comment: U can use the "distance" function of the **QgsGeometry** class, it returns the minimum distance between two geometries (u just have to set these two geometries : your point and the nearest feature u found)

Comment: Yep - getting there! Once I nail it down (and if not beaten to it) I'll post my code.

Answer (score 8):

Everything's easy when you know how...
For simplicity I've put the point's coordinates in here.

```
#define the point
pt = QgsPoint(289749,56754)
pt =  QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt)

#get the active polygon
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
polygon = layer.getFeatures().next()
geom = polygon.geometry()

#do the business    
distanceToPolygon = QgsGeometry.distance(pt, geom)
print distanceToPolygon
```

Comment: _"Everything's easy when you know how"_ - Such a true statement! +1.